Coupon form after order total removes customer data when applying a coupon in WooCommerce Checkout
I have made some adjustments to my WooCommerce checkout (code that places the discount code elsewhere). It's working but when this code is added and a customer applies a discount code it removes all the information the customer has already filled out, so that they need to write their name, address, email and phone again.
How do I adjust this code to prevent the data being removed, forcing the customer to enter it twice?
/*
 * Removing default "Coupon form" from the top of the checkout page
 */
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );

/*
 * Hooking "Coupon form" after order total in checkout page with custom function
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom' );

/*
 * Rendering html for "Coupon form" with custom function
 */
function woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom() {
    echo '<tr class="coupon-form"><td colspan="2">';
    wc_get_template(
        'checkout/form-coupon.php',
        array(
            'checkout' => WC()->checkout(),
        )
    );
    echo '</td></tr>';
}

/* Åben rabatkode felt */

//Tilpas CSS
function mujuonly_add_inline_css() {

    $mustlogin_custom_css = "
        .woocommerce-form-coupon {
            display:block !important;
        }
    ";

  //Styling i CSS visningen
  wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce-inline', $mustlogin_custom_css ); //Variabel videregives til sheet

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mujuonly_add_inline_css' ); //CSS style


what is the content of checkout/form-coupon.php

Here https://codeshare.io/Bd8LNb

i can't even guess what happens when you click submit i guess it runs agsin into the start page, there are some debug tool sthat can help you to help yourself see https://developer.woocommerce.com/testing-extensions-and-maintaining-quality-code/debugging-tools/

It reloads the page and info has to be filled anew

@eMikkelsen Is your site live? can you link me to it? I'd like to see what your site is doing on the front end wit this coupon button. Thanks

just a hack..
after
<div class="flex-col">
    <button type="submit"
        class="button expand<?php if ( fl_woocommerce_version_check( '7.0.1' ) ) { echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); } ?>"
        name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </button>

add
    <script>
        // bad "remember fields" hack
        $("[name='apply_coupon']").on("click", function () {
            let savedInputFields = {};
            $("input").each(function () {
                if (
                    $(this).val() == ""
                    || $(this).attr("type") == "hidden"
                    || $(this).attr("type") == "submit"
                    || $(this).attr("readonly")
                ) {
                    return;
                }
                // if it has an id, use #id, otherwise use [name='name']
                if ($(this).attr("id")) {
                    savedInputFields["#" + $(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
                } else if ($(this).attr("name")) {
                    savedInputFields["[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']"] = $(this).val();
                } else {
                    console.log("Warning: No id or name found for input field", this);
                }
            });
            localStorage.setItem("savedInputFieldsHack", JSON.stringify(savedInputFields));
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            let savedInputFields = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("savedInputFieldsHack"));
            if (savedInputFields) {
                for (let key in savedInputFields) {
                    $(key).val(savedInputFields[key]);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

untested but should work in theory.

Doesn't work -> syntax error, unexpected token "<", expecting end of file

@eMikkelsen do you see the source of the syntax error? cus i don't. do you get the syntax error if you just add  <script></script> ?
